# Reference or a mathematical equation for R squared and adjusted R squared for panel models used in the R package plm

Tags: r, panel-data, r-squared, plm

I'm using [plm](/questions/tagged/plm) in [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I'm trying t o find out exactly how `R squared` and `adjusted R squared` is calculated for panel models in [plm](/questions/tagged/plm).

I looked at [this plm man page](https://rdrr.io/rforge/plm/man/r.squared.html), on which I can [view the source code](https://rdrr.io/rforge/plm/src/R/plm.R), but it did not have any references or further links. The source code is a bit complex for me to deconstruct. Normally the man pages are very good with references or links, but I can't seem to find my way here. Any help would be appreciated. I realize this might be incredibly simply.

Comment: Hello Eric, could you clarify what is not clear for you exactly? Do you know what the [R squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Definitions) and [adjusted R squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2) are for a linear model or not? I mean, is the question specific to R's `plm` package implementation of this metrics or is the question about the metrics themselves?

Comment: @byouness, thank you for your question. I was looking in the `plm` documentation to see the references to how `R squared` and `adjusted R squared` and that spurred my question. Maybe the issue is so self evident that they did not put references. I am simply question to know/understand the exact formula used. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: The R squared and adjusted R squared are very common, and there is no ambiguity regarding their definitions, so if you check the wikipedia links I joined in my first comment, you should get the answer you're looking for :) If you have specific questions about the `plm` implementation then maybe I, or someone else, can have a look. But if the question is about R squared in general, I guess the wikipedia page is enough and this question should be closed. Thanks!

Comment: There is no problem with asking a question on CV when the answer might exist on Wikipedia. That said, see if the information you need is in the linked thread.